# How to customize a table group consistently

Tags: html, css

### The goal

Customize a *table group* consistently.

### The problem

There is the following table on my application:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="xbox360"><strong>Xbox 360</strong></td>
            <td><strong>PS3</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Xbox One</strong></td>
            <td><strong>PS4</strong></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Market A</strong></td>
            <td class="xbox360">US$299,00</td>
            <td>US$329,00</td>
            <td>US$499,00</td>
            <td>US$399,00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Market B</strong></td>
            <td class="xbox360">US$289,00</td>
            <td>US$319,00</td>
            <td>US$489,00</td>
            <td>US$389,00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What I need is simple: treat the column `xbox360` as if it were one single thing. In other words, I don't want a class to customize this column.

### To play

[Click here to play on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DXm69/)

Comment: why don't you assign it a different class?

Comment: @DanielA.White Sorry, but I don't understood your idea.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a class?

Comment: I can use a class, @MikeW. But I want to customize the column as a one single thing. I mean, I don't want there to be the white spaces between the lines of a column.

Comment: tbody>tr td:first-child+td{background:#000;}

Comment: `table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}`

Answer (score 4):

If I understood you correctly:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DXm69/3/)

More on [border-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse).

Comment: This seems to be what the requester was asking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use `colgroup`:

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col />
        <col class="xbox360" />
        <col />
        <col />
        <col />
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
    ...
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now your *xbox360* class will be applied to the entire column as one. But, beware that only a few styles can be applied using col-colgroup. I think width, text-align etc.

**Edit**:

After your comment on removing spacing: Combine it with `border-collapse: collapse;` on table (as suggested by others).

*Check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DXm69/4/*

**As for your original question on treating the column as a whole group, `colgroup` (along with class) is the best option.**

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```